# How to fill recess in fireplace before tiling

Tags: fireplace, brick, masonry, tiling, cement

I wish to tile a fireplace pictured below
[image]
The brickwork has a recessed area directly above the firebox (pictured below)
[image]
This recessed area measures 28" x 8" x 1-1/2"
I wish to tile over the recessed area flush with the rest of the fireplace front.  In other words:  Remove the recessed area.  My thought is to fill this area with a non-combustible material like durock.  Not sure what the best material would be, though.  Seems to me that it would be easier to use something thicker and lighter.

I was also thinking of making a mold and filling it with a high-performance cement.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree with you. Use three layers of 1/2" Durock. Attach all 3 plies at the same time to the brick with 2-1/4" Phillips Tapcon concrete screws.

Durock is certified as non-combustible tested to ASTM E136, “Standard Test Method for the Behavior of Materials in a Vertical Tube Furnace at 750°C” and therefore is acceptable in use as a fireplace facing.

Comment: FIRE CLAY OR MORTER! these are designed for direct contact with hot embers, I usually use fire mortar because it is designed to seal and protect the lower surface like a wood stove brick is better able to handle some heat but needs to be sealed.

Comment: Thank you Jeff and Ed.  Ed- just to clarify:  Are you saying that Durock is not an adequate material for this application?  The material used would not receive direct contact from embers, it would get pretty hot though.  I'll do some research on fire clay and fire morter to try to figure out what it would take to use that material.  My first thought is that I would have to construct some kind of metal supporting structure.  Thanks again.

Comment: @laertiades Personally I would still use Durock, but Hardibacker is also acceptable: Both Durock and Hardibacker are certified as non-combustible tested to ASTM E136, “Standard Test Method for the Behavior of Materials in a Vertical Tube Furnace at 750°C” and therefore is acceptable in use as a fireplace facing.